# Pass complex state and setState to simpler api's

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Suppose I have a Simple React Component, which accepts a state, and a callback which must provide the current state as a parameter like React's setState does, so that MyFC can calculate the next state.

```
interface MyFCProps{
 state: number[];
 setState: (oldState: number[]) => number[];
};
const MyFC: React.FC<MyFCProps> = (props) => { /* some magic */ }
```

But in our parent component where we want to call this component, we have a object as state (might contain more than 10-15 key-value pairs);

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState<{s1: number[]; s2: number[]}>({s1: []; s2: []});
```

I want MyFC to not care about the complex nestest state, but only deal with state.s1 and to only care about apdating it.
Example:

```
<MyFC state={state.s1} setState={??}/>
```

But how do I write the setState ?
Had this been a simple state of a primitive value, i could just pass the `React.Dispatch` that  `React.useState` returns, but now what?

How to I create a new function out of `setState` function, where the parameter will be `state.s1` and return value will be `state.s1` keeping the other object key-values as is.

One thing that comes to mind is to use `React.flushSync` to use the old state and immediately update the value in our custom setState, and bypass React batching state updates. This will eliminate having to use `oldState` as a parameter of useState and we can simply implement this function outside MyFC.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the goal is to create a `setState` that updates value of a specific key in a `state` object, which also support a setter function as an argument (similar to the original `set` function), I think a possible solution could be `useReducer`, since it has access to the current state in reducer function.

This approach might be over simplified depending on the use case, but here is an experimental example.

Demo of the basic example on: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-jjaii5?file=src/App.tsx)

Configure `reducer` so that it sets the `payload` value to the matching key in the state object. If the value is a setter function, execute it with current `state[key]` as argument, and set the returned value instead.

```
type SetterArg = number[] | ((p?: number[]) => number[]);

interface MyAction {
  key: string;
  payload?: SetterArg;
}

interface MyState {
  [key: string]: number[];
}

const reducer = (state: MyState, action: MyAction) => {
  const { key, payload } = action;
  if (!key || !payload) return { ...state };
  switch (typeof payload) {
    case 'object': {
      if (!Array.isArray(payload)) return { ...state };
      return {
        ...state,
        [key]: payload,
      };
    }
    case 'function': {
      return {
        ...state,
        [key]: payload(state[key]),
      };
    }
    default: {
      return { ...state };
    }
  }
};
```

In the parent component, create a recipe function `handleSetState` that generates the `setState` needed by children component. A matching `key` is wired up with the individual `setState`, so the logic within children component could be simplified.

```
const initial: MyState = { s1: [1, 2, 3], s2: [1, 2] };

function App() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initial);
  //  Recipe for generating setState for children
  const handleSetState = (key: string) => (payload: SetterArg) =>
    dispatch({ key: key, payload: payload });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h4> MyFC</h4>
      <MyFC state={state['s1']} setState={handleSetState('s1')} />
      <h4> Another FC</h4>
      <MyFC state={state['s2']} setState={handleSetState('s2')} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

With `state` and `setState` passed to `MyFC`, the children component can then use `setState` in a way similar to the original `set` function (for the `state` relevant to this component only).

```
interface MyFCProps {
  state: number[];
  setState: (arg: SetterArg) => void;
}

const MyFC = ({ state, setState }: MyFCProps) => {
  //  Pass a value or setter function to setState
  const handleAdd = () =>
    setState((prev) => {
      if (!prev || prev.length === 0) return [1];
      const last = prev[prev.length - 1];
      return [...prev, last + 1];
    });

  const handleRemove = () =>
    setState((prev) => {
      if (!prev || prev.length === 0) return [];
      const removed = prev.filter((item, index) => index !== prev.length - 1);
      return removed;
    });

  return (
    <section>
      <h3>{`I have state value: ${
        state.length === 0 ? ' empty' : state.join(', ')
      }`}</h3>
      <div>
        <button onClick={handleAdd}>Add</button>
        <button onClick={handleRemove}>Remove</button>
        <button onClick={() => setState([])}>Clear all</button>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};
```